# postgresql multiple insert with select query

Tags: postgresql, select, insert

i need to perform a insert query for multiple rows whereby the first column is a  numeric and identical value and the second values are queried from another table.

something like

insert into table (33, select col2 from another_table);

can this be accomplished with a single statement?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

like this

```
insert into table 
select 33, col2 from another_table;
```

Comment: in this example, the table being inserted must have only two fields: one that will receive the numeric and another of the same type as col2 from another_table

Comment: I was wondering if there was a possibility to specify columns explicitly like: insert into table (id, col2_name) values((select 33, col2 from another_table)) ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to specify columns in your insert query, you should use this syntax:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, col2_name) (SELECT 33, col2 FROM another_table);
```